# Xcode iAd iPhone 6 & 6 Plus

Tags: iphone, iad

i try using iAd in my App. But when i use it in iPhone 6 and 6 Plus there is space and the right and left? Is that normal? Because at iphone 5 and 4 its totally normal.

Thanks for help

Dave

Comment: in portrait it should use the entire screen width! have you added some constraints to the banner which could cause him to layout incorrectly?

Comment: You need to add how you are creating/laying out your `ADBannerView` to your question.